# How to save and stop MS Office process with powershell?

Tags: powershell

I need to close the word/excel/powerpoint documents from taskbar with powershell script. Stop-process kills the process but it doesnt save the changes made. I need it to save and close the document. I am able to do it for word with following script:

```
$wd = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Word.Application')
$wd.Documents | % { $_.Close() }
Get-Process | ?{$_.ProcessName -eq "WINWORD"} | Stop-Process
```

When I do the same for excel and powerpoint I get error message and the changes are not saved. 
For Excel I have done as follows:

```
$excel = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
$excel.ActiveWorkbook | % { $_.Close() }
Get-Process | ?{$_.ProcessName -eq "EXCEL"} | Stop-Process
```

For powerpoint:

```
$ppt= [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Powerpoint.Application')
$ppt.Presentations | % { $_.Close() }
Get-Process | ?{$_.ProcessName -eq "POWERPOINT"} | Stop-Process
```

Error displayed is:

```
+             $excel.ActiveWorkbook | % { $_.Close() }
+                                         ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Close:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Comment: Isn't there a line with the error message missing from that error output? You may be able to call `$excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\path\to\new.xlsx")` before `Close()` to save the document

Comment: Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] doesn't contain a method named 'Close'.
At close.ps1:22 char:32
+             $excel.ActiveWorkbook | % { $_.Close() }
+                                         ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Close:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Answer (score 2):

This will prompt for save if needed and then close Excel:
(Get-Process -Name "Excel").CloseMainWindow

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false; $excel.Workbooks | % { $_.Save(); $_.Close() }
```

Comment: I am getting still getting the same error with this code

Comment: Can you please post the Error again. Also, you can use `$excel.Quit()` to close Excel instead of using `Get-Process | ?{$_.ProcessName -eq "EXCEL"} | Stop-Process`

Comment: Exception setting "DisplayAlerts": "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"
At G:\close.ps1:25 char:4
+             $excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting

Comment: Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] doesn't contain a method named 'Save'.
At G:\close.ps1:26 char:27
+             $excel.Workbooks | % { $_.Save(); $_.Close() }
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] doesn't contain a method named 'Close'.
At G:\lose.ps1:26 char:38
+             $excel.Workbooks | % { $_.Save(); $_.Close() }
+                                               ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: It does work IF you correctly reference `$excel.workbook`

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember where I got the base code for this but if anyone finds it please give the due credit. I modified it for your use case:

```
$isExcelOpen = Get-Process excel*
while ($isExcelOpen -ne $null) {
       Get-Process excel* | ForEach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Null }
       sleep 5
       If (($isExcelOpen = Get-Process excel*) -ne $null) {
              Write-Host "Excel is Open.......Closing Excel"
              $wshell = new-object -com wscript.shell
              $wshell.AppActivate("Microsoft Excel")
              $wshell.Sendkeys("%(S)")
              $isExcelOpen = Get-Process excel*
       }
}
```

You will need to change excel to word/powerpoint and possibly $wshell.Sendkeys to the proper letter